# Writing to disk using `pv` seems to be fast at first and slow at the end

Tags: command-line, disk-image

I was writing a Kubuntu image to my USB stick using this command

```
pv /home/manuel/Downloads/torrents/kubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64.iso > /dev/sdb
```

However, the output progress bar of `pv` was half-filled right from the very beginning. Hence, it looked like transmission would have started with an incredible speed and slowed down substantially.

```
1,49GiB 0:03:03 [8,31MiB/s] [===============// //===============>] 100%
```

That makes using the `pv` command rather useless.

How can I disable this caching functionality which seems to have been activated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found your post while looking into a similar issue trying to write an image to an SD card (via USB reader/writer). Using pv, it would show 100% almost immediately, but take several minutes afterwards to actually complete.

I found a solution to my issue using `dd`, `pv` and pipes, and setting the write dd to direct mode. This also has had the effect of improving the write speed quite a lot. I don't know if there are any downsides of using this method (I read the image back and performed a checksum - and all appears ok).

My example is using an image of raspbian (2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img), which is 1854590976 bytes (1.8GB) in size. I've shown a couple of other methods and you can see the differences in time taken.

So, using `dd | pv | dd` with direct mode, it took only 2 minutes 57 seconds:

```
dd if=2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img ibs=1M status=none | pv -s 1854590976 | dd of=/dev/sdX obs=1M oflag=direct status=none
```

*(setting status to none stops `dd` messing up the `pv` display).*

Using `pv` by itself shows 100% immediately, but then took 8 minutes 28 seconds to actually complete:

```
pv 2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img > /dev/sdX
```

Using `dd` by itself without any progress view, took 8 minutes 15 seconds:

```
dd if=2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1M
```

Using the same `dd` above but adding `oflag=direct` makes it 2 minutes 54:

```
dd if=2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1M oflag=direct
```

I've tried loads of different combinations, which are either far slower (some take up to 12 minutes!), or again show 100% immediately.

One caveat of using `pv` this way is that you need to find out the size of the image first, and specify it with the `-s` option. If you're scripting things like me, it's easy enough to determine the file size at the same time.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Nice thorough answer, but based on your results, piping `dd` through `pv` had no noticeable effect, and it was the adding of the `oflag=direct` option that resulted in the speed gains.

Comment: Any idea how to make this a bash alias? I find it hard to memorize the exact syntax and would like to put a `pv-direct='...'` alias to my `~/.bash_aliases`

Answer (score 1):

According to...

```
dd if=2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1M oflag=direct
```

I modified that a bit...

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -tearp -s 1820g | dd of=/dev/sda bs=100M oflag=direct
```

An imediate answer of dd: `suggest iflag=fullblock`

So I did...

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -tearp -s 1820g | dd of=/dev/sda bs=100M iflag=fullblock
```

The writing rate jumped from `56,3 MiB/s` to `122MiB/s`

That meant time needed to fill a 2TB HDD

was made short from about 9 hours to 4 hours.

Equipment:

```
        ASUS x77vg
        4GB Memory
        Linux Mate 18.3
        HDD: Seagate ST2000LM015-2E81 - Size: 1863GiB
```

Hope that helps someone...

Comment: I am not sure `iflag=fullblock` is a good idea. I tried it with your 100M recommendation on an older USB thumb drive with only 64MB and i threw an error `dd: error writing '/dev/sde': No space left on device` but wrote 64MB successfully although the image is only a few MB in size. This is not what I needed.